# Unsure why argument is being altered by while loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Very (*very, very*) new to Ruby, so apologies for this awful code.

I have the following 2d array;

```
test = [
  ['Z','M','Z','Z','Z'],
  ['Z','Z','M','M','Z'],
  ['Z','Z','M','Z','Z'],
  ['Z','Z','Z','Z','Z'],
  ['Z','M','Z','Z','M']
]
```

and I'd like to return the adjacent cells (up to 8) of every cell in the array. I'm trying this on a row-by-row basis, using 'while' to loop through each sub-array until I hit an index that's out of bounds.

I'm sure this is horribly inefficient, dumb etc, but for now it's where my head is!

When I call the method as per the below, passing the arguments (test, 0, 4), it correctly works it's way along the 'x' indices, but I am absolutely baffled as to why my 'y' argument gets changed from a '4' to a '1' after the first loop.

What am I missing?

```
def do_the_cells_in_one_row grid,x=0,y=0
  while grid[y][x].nil? == false
    puts "here's x: #{x} y: #{y}"
    puts grid[y][x]

    if (x-1).negative? == false
      print grid[y][x-1] 
      print y
      puts x-1
    end

    if (x-1).negative? == false && (y-1).negative? ==false
      print grid[y-1][x-1]
      print y-1
      puts x
    end

    if (y+1) < grid.length && (x-1).negative? == false
      print grid[y+1][x-1]
      print y+1 
      puts x-1
    end

    if (y+1) < grid.length
      print grid[y+1][x]
      print y+1
      puts x
    end

    if (y-1).negative? == false
      print grid[y-1][x]
      print y-1
      puts x
    end

    if  x+1 < grid[y].length
      print grid[y][x+1]
      print y
      puts x+1
    end

    if  y+1 < grid.length && x+1 < grid[y].length
      print grid[y+1][x+1]
      print y+1
      puts x+1
    end

    if (y-1).negative? == false && (x+1) < grid[y].length
      print grid[y-1][x+1]
      print y-1
      puts x+1
    end

    x += 1
  end
end

do_the_cells_in_one_row(test,0,4)
```

**EDIT** updated the code as per the comments! Running straight into another problem unfortunately. I'm trying this to then loop the code through each subarray;

```
def do_every_row grid,x=0,y=0
  while grid[y][x].nil? == false
    do_the_cells_in_one_row(grid,x,y)
    y += 1
  end
end
```

get the following error

```
in `do_every_row': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

but unsure why!

Comment: I spy a `print y=1` where you meant `print y+1` in one of your if statements.

Comment: oh dear. Thank you! It's been a long day :-/

Comment: Happens to everybody. No worries. For future reference, I just did a CTRL+F of your code for the expression `y=`. That sort of thing can help in identifying typos if you ever run into something like this again.

Comment: much appreciated. Not sure if I have the option to upvote your comment at this stage!

Comment: Maybe you need to swap x with y here `while grid[x][y].nil? == false`? Try to use `each` instead of `while`, it's more Ruby-ish.

Comment: thanks @iGian - that doesn't seem to work though if I add more sub-arrays... it'll just stop iterating once the 'row' value exceed the length of each subarray, instead of doing every row. Keeping that line as 'while grid[y][x].nil? == false' does iterate successfully through the whole 2d array even if I add more sub-arrays, but then throws the error. Will see if I can refactor this using each once I understand why the current one isn't working!

Comment: Be careful swapping `x` and `y`, since it changes behaviour. The reason this fails is because `grid[y] #=> nil`. So when calling `grid[y][x]` you get an undefined method `[]` for nil:NilClass because `nil`. Use `grid[y].nil?` instead, since you only care about that coordinate.

Comment: I also have the feeling that `puts x` should be `puts x - 1` in your second *if* statement. I stumbled upon it when [refactoring your code](https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/d44a420cb81187fe5d064a8486ef6b64) and got an different output. Code can be further reduced with a few different tweaks, for example using you could use a [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Range.html) instead of the *while* loop. `while grid[y][x].nil? == false` can be replaced with `(x...grid[y].length).each do |x|` removing the need to up `x` each cycle.

Comment: amazing, thanks very much @JohanWentholt, that's all really useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last iteration, when Ruby tries to evaluate the expression `grid[y][x].nil? == false`, y is out of boundary `y = 5`. When Ruby moves on to the next concatenated method it throws an error because `grid[y] = nil`, therefore the former expression is interpreted as `nil[x].nil? == false`.

In Ruby, methods are defined in every class, hence the error occurs because you're trying to use an Array class method `[]` with a Nil object (which is an instance of NilClass and doesn't have that method).

A simple solution would be to compare y against the length of the array. In this case, `while y < grid.length`

Comment: thanks Giorgio. Any idea why I didn't see the nil error with the contained method for do_the_cells_in_one_row?

Comment: ah, because of the order... there's a nil value, but the .nil? method works on those

Comment: Because in the first method the second index `x` is the one changing, so `grid[y]` never evaluates to nil, therefore Ruby never has the problem of evaluating `nil[x]`. You are correct on your second comment :)